# dispaying foreign fields based on relations

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have the folowing schema:

```
 catalogue:
  actAs: [Timestampable, Sortable]
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(2)
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    catalogue_name:
      type: varchar(255)
  relations:
    catalogue:
        class: Product
        refClass: ProductPrices
        local: catalogue_id
        foreign: product_id
ProductPrices:
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    product_id: { type: integer(4)}
    catalogue_id: { type: integer(2) }
    price: { type:real }
  relations:
    Product:    { local: product_id, foreign: id }
    catalogue:  { local: catalogue_id, foreign: id }
  indexes:
    unique_price:  { fields: [catalogue_id, product_id], type: unique }
Product:
  actAs:             [Timestampable]
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    product_code:
      type: varchar(10)
    product_desc:
      type: varchar(255)
    created_at:
      type: timestamp
  relations:
    catalogue:
        class: catalogue
        refClass: ProductPrices
        local: product_id
        foreign: catalogue_id
```

Now this is a many-to-man relaionsip between `Product` and `catalogue`

What I'm looking to do, is to display each Catalogue and it's products, in a HTML table.

I have created a compenent and a Doctrine query:

```
public static function getPricingTable()
{
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
      ->from('ProductPrices p');

   return $q->execute();
}
```

Now,  my only problem is now displaying the catalogues and the products, i.e.

Catalogue 1

```
* Product 1     
* Product 2        
* Product 3
```

Catalogue 2

```
* Product 1
```

All help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all products of a catalogue, you just have to use the **getProduct()** method of a catalogue instance.

For example, if you want to get all catalogues with all products:

```
$catalogues = Doctrine::getTable('catalogue')->findAll();

foreach($catalogues as $catalogue){
   //$catalogue is an instance
   echo $catalogue->getCatalogueName()

   //you've got all products from a catalogue instance    
   foreach($catalogue->getProduct() as $product){
       echo $product->getProductDesc();
   }
}
```